# Excel checkboxes and buttons stopped working on spreadsheet

Tags: excel, button, checkbox

I have a spreadsheet that uses macros.  It has been working fine for years, and it has been an xlsm for almost a year now.  It uses buttons and checkboxes to control the macros.  Just last week, all of the checkboxes and buttons stopped working.  We replaced the buttons and now they work, but the checkboxes would be more difficult to replace so I was hoping there was a way to fix them.

[image: Visual of Problem]

In the image above, the left-hand side shows this new behavior, where the checkbox cannot be checked.  Instead, the cursor shows up as a large plus and it displays the value of the checkbox.

On the right is an earlier version of the spreadsheet where the correct behavior is exhibitied.  The cursor becomes an arrow and the user is allowed to check.

Note that I am *not* in design mode.

When I enter design mode, right click on the checkbox, and go to properties, there are no properties for the checkbox.  When I select the dropdown menu on the top of the properties window, the checkboxes are not in the list of items.  The buttons, which are currently functioning after they were replaced, do not show up in the dropdown list either.  In the old spreadsheet that works, all buttons and checkboxes are listed.

[image]

Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks!

The original question comes up in Google now and mine does not so I agree duplicate.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question 4 years later?  I cannot delete it?  Thanks for all the bad reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pnuts comment solved the problem.  I had to delete my .exd files because the December 2014 update messed up the functionality.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/archive/2014/12/13/forms-controls-stop-working-after-december-2014-updates-.aspx

I hope others find the solution linked through the post.

Comment: If I search for "excel buttons stopped working", this is the only result I found with this problem/solution.  Thanks!